# Why does numpy.cov(a,a) not give autocorrelations in all quadrants?

Tags: python, numpy, covariance

I am calculating covariances for a dataset and trying to tes tmy code against numpy.

I have 100 simulations. and 256 values, so my starting arrays have shape (100, 256).

To test how the np.cov function works, I tried feeding it two idential arrays i.e. np.cov(a,a).

I expected that cov(a,b) returns
(cov(a,a), cov(a,b)
(cov(b,a), cov(b,b)

so I thought for the same matrix I should get
cov(a,a) cov(a,a)
cov(a,a) cov(a,a)

but this doesnt seem to be the case.

```
Pow_i = Pk_dd_pow
Pow_j = Pk_dd_pow
numpy_cov= np.cov(np.array(np.real(Pk_pow_i)).T, np.array(np.real(Pk_pow_j)).T)
```

gives numpy_cov as a (512,512) array, as I was expecting. But..

```
left_upper = numpy_cov[0:256,0:256]
right_upper=  numpy_cov[256:513,0:256]
right_lower = numpy_cov[256:513,256:513]
left_lower = numpy_cov[0:256,256:513]
print(np.array_equal(right_lower, left_upper))
print(np.array_equal(left_lower, right_upper))
print(np.array_equal(right_lower, right_upper))
print(np.array_equal(left_lower, left_upper))
print(np.array_equal(left_lower, right_lower))
```

returns

```
True
True
False
False
False
```

I thought all four should give the auto covariance, so why are they different? PLease help! :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear that it would yield this, but what you can do is **try on smaller sized arrays** as a more basic example like this:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])
b = np.array([[10,20,30,40,50],[10,20,30,40,50]])

numpy_cov_aa = np.cov(a,a)
numpy_cov_ab = np.cov(a, b)
numpy_cov_ba = np.cov(b, a)
numpy_cov_bb = np.cov(b, b)

print(numpy_cov_aa)
print('---')
print(numpy_cov_ab)
print('---')
print(numpy_cov_ba)
print('---')
print(numpy_cov_bb)
```

which returns this:

```
[[2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5]
 [2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5]
 [2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5]
 [2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5]]
---
[[  2.5   2.5  25.   25. ]
 [  2.5   2.5  25.   25. ]
 [ 25.   25.  250.  250. ]
 [ 25.   25.  250.  250. ]]
---
[[250.  250.   25.   25. ]
 [250.  250.   25.   25. ]
 [ 25.   25.    2.5   2.5]
 [ 25.   25.    2.5   2.5]]
---
[[250. 250. 250. 250.]
 [250. 250. 250. 250.]
 [250. 250. 250. 250.]
 [250. 250. 250. 250.]]
```

This has the advantage of being more observable to you.

And from here you can inspect if this extends to what you were expecting...